# Tunnels under the ocean

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, mines

So I build a city on the ocean floor out of handwavium, Bioshock style, but I want an easier way to get there besides taking a boat to the middle of nowhere and then getting into a submersible.

I have an idea to dig a shaft deep into the ocean floor, and then make a tunnel leading to a near-by island, and if it goes well maybe extending to the mainland eventually.

Obviously once you go down to the ocean bottom there is a lot of pressure, but I'm thinking that by going down below the bottom the seabed will provide enough support to keep my tunnel from collapsing so I can have a dry path to run a rail line.

Is this a workable plan?

The feasibility of the city itself isn't a concern with this question. I'm just looking at a way to get to it.

Comment: Why not dig the whole city into the bedrock? what's the advantage of putting it on the sea floor?

Comment: Why not build the tunnel out of the same stuff as the city buildings?

Comment: @James The view.

Comment: @colmde It's cost prohibitive, too visible, and that's a lot to keep structurally sound. A few building shells don't use all that much material, and can be designed with the right structural shapes to give it the most strength. And being out of shipping lanes keeps them from being noticed. But a super long tube would be more prone to leaking and breaking, and since it's so long, going to an inhabited island, it would be more noticeable.

Comment: Plate tectonics. I have this vision of a tunnel going through a plate boundary with another plate.

Comment: @JustinThyme I was thinking of putting it in the middle of a plate. Maybe the Caribbean plate, maybe up on the west side of Greenland...

Comment: If you can build an entire city on the ocean floor, why can't you build a shaft from the city to the surface, and put in an elevator? Average depth of the ocean is 3,700 meters, the CN tower is 553 meters, the tallest building is 828 meters, so a shaft wide enough to provide stability is not beyond reason. Four times the height of the tallest building. The CN tower can withstand the impact of a fully loaded fully fueled 747.

Comment: @JustinThyme Mostly so it won't get too much attention to start with. An oil drilling platform or something like that receiving huge shipments of goods and loads of people is going to look suspicious. But a seaside village would be a lot less so.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of just the hatch being visible, and the supply ships disguised as ocean-going fishing plants (whalers). Not unusual for them to stay stationary for long periods, then move on. The flexible docking mechanism would all be below the surface.

Comment: how deep is deep,  and is your city on oceanic or continental crust?

Comment: @AndyD273 re: The View. There would not be much to see; it's basically night after 200 meters: https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/light_travel.html If you were near anything interesting at that depth - hydrothermal vents, methane seeps -- the geology would likely be unsuitable for construction.

Comment: @John Oh, for now lets say right on the edge of the continental shelf, just before it falls off. I assume your question has to do with a difference between building on basalt vs bedrock?

Comment: Here is a video of what you are in for, in terms of provisioning [Two thousand crew, 10 hours and 700 tons of supplies: Incredible time-lapse video shows turnaround of world's largest cruise ships](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3465103/Cruise-ship-food-10-680-hot-dogs-just-tip-iceberg.html) That is a LOT of stuff to move through a tunnel.

Comment: @AndyD273, +1 for the giggle at "the view", but have you seen footage of the ocean floor? Its night time down there. There is no view. Also, you gave yourself an allowance in your own question. If you accept unobtainium to build your city then that should extend to the tunnels. I like your idea though.

Comment: How cool would it look lit up though, What an amazing train journey through a glass tunnel at the bottom of the sea, with lights lighting say 50 metres of sea floor around the tunnel.

Comment: @n00dles This is true...

Comment: As you start out with "handwavium" that withstands the pressures and whatever else is required, this all seems like a non-problem as you can build a tunnel to and from with the same materials.

Comment: Taking a submarine all the way to the undersea city seems much simpler.

Comment: @M.A.Golding It's both simple and complex. Things like underwater passive sonar sensors and the like would notice the traffic, and if there was enough of it someone might decide to come investigate. There is also the matter of volume when it comes to moving goods. Moving big shipping containers by sub would need a really big sub. Boat is more realistic probably. And I guess if the containers were properly sealed you could just drop a few over the side, and send someone out to bring them in. But I also like the idea of an under water city you can get to without going in the water.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the depth and length (and expenses) of undersea tunnels like the [Seikan Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seikan_Tunnel). If you consider the [Yoshioka-Kaitei Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshioka-Kaitei_Station) an undersea base, there is even that. This example shows that a tunnel is *in principle* feasible.

Many of the considerations for an undersea base apply to the tunnel -- if one is feasible, so is the other.

- Keeping the walls watertight.
- Quakes.

Comment: Note: I'd section the tunnel, with regular water-locks and multiple parallel tunnels. This way, if you lose a section, you can (1) get around it and (2) get into it with losing another section (for repairs...).

Answer (score 11):

The deep oceans floors are made of Basalt ([Mid ocean ridge basalt](https://www.britannica.com/science/mid-ocean-ridge-basalt), or MORB). This is unfortunately quite permeable to seawater (and even to [oil](https://www.slb.com/~/media/Files/resources/oilfield_review/ors09/spr09/evaluating_volcanic_reservoirs.pdf)), so a tunnel would tend to fill with water quite quickly.  Above the basalt is often a layer of mud with little mechanical strength.

Your best bet is surely to have a tube of Unobtanium on the ocean bed, or at least line your tunnel with it. Lining the tunnel removes the problems of mechanical strength and water ingress.

Comment: I wonder, if it would be possible to line it with something less imaginary if the tunnel is going through the basalt. Something like steel or whatever.

Comment: digging into the basalt makes the pressure problem worse not better.

Comment: Steel is unlikely to be necessary - if the basalt is strong enough by itself (I have no idea how strong basalt is, to be honest) then concrete can be made adequately enough waterproof that simply having a gradient on your tunnel and a sump with pumps to remove any water that accumulates at the bottom end would probably be good enough.

Answer (score 8):

This is less difficult than building the city itself.

The key is to pressurize the tunnel, in the same way you have probably pressurized the city. Especially with a train system, an airlock near the entrance would not be difficult. The deepest tunnel now is the [Ekiksund Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiksund_Tunnel) at 287m under the water. Even if we take twice that depth as the engineering limit for non-pressure regulated tunnels, you're going to be fairly limited in locations. The oceans are mostly very deep.

[image: infographic of lake and ocean depths]

Image source is [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1040/).

Pressurizing the air in both the city and the tunnel will make the engineering much easier. It also adds some safe limits on how quickly people can leave your city. So for the case of the tunnel, you may wish to have the train itself pressurized differently than the surrounding air. This will allow the train to slowly lower the pressure as it approaches the surface.

The other obvious option is to simply have the tunnel filled with water. Adding aerators will lower the average density of the water and allow the pressurized train to pass more quickly than if it were in pure water.

Comment: `300m == 30bar` That is, your pressurized air will have roughly 30 times the density of air at sea level. That's a bit thick for comfort. Both for the humans (nitrogen narcosis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_narcosis !) and for the trains driving through this thick medium (energy consumption at relevant speeds). So, unless you are willing to pressurize the city with helium (expensive), you are limited to very shallow waters with this approach.

Comment: don't rip [XKCDs](https://xkcd.com/1040/) without credit. Not least, the compress is not readable.

Comment: @cmaster Obviously you won't be at full pressure or, if you are, it won't be at normal atmospheric mix. An under-ocean city probably won't have a problem with paying for a helium/oxygen mix.

Comment: @Harper Actually the image came from [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/ocean-depth-infographic-2016-6), who obviously got it from xkcd (which by the way, is the preferred format). It's clearly from xkcd, I doubt anyone would be confused, but thanks for getting the link. The depth on the side is the key point and is legible.

Comment: Of course, you can reduce the impact of the pressurization by reducing the pressure. My point is, pressurization can only make up for a few hundred meters at most, and even at that, its impact is humongous. To scale: 40m is pretty much the limit for recreational scuba diving (with pressurized air due to nitrogen narcosis). Beneath that, you already need experts to manage the risk. At 100m, there is no way of diving without helium. That is a rough sketch of the range of depths that you can compensate for with pressure. A sub that's pressurized to 10 bar can only dive 100m deeper...

Comment: @cmaster Humans can survive with no ill effects at [pressures equivalent to 20 bar when helium is used for the diluent gas](https://history.nasa.gov/conghand/mannedev.htm). True, this is only about 200 meters equivalent pressure. But I'm not suggesting that pressurization allows for infinite depth. Only that it allows for deeper than a similar unpressurized tunnel. Do you disagree? Also note that the primary danger in diving is the potential need to surface quickly, in this case with a city underwater, people are not likely to surface quickly.

Comment: @Samuel No, when you put it like that, I do not disagree. Merely pointing out that those 200 meters are pretty much all you can get. I also agree that surfacing is not a problem, but do not underestimate the danger of nitrogen narcosis: It can induce hallucinations; and your ability to think straight is the very last thing you want to loose when all that stands between you and death is your ability to get back to the surface in time.

Comment: @cmaster I'm a certified diver. I've heard the horror stories. I imagine living in an underwater city would induce more than a bit of claustrophobia and general angst in the population. It would for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you did such a tunnel, you will have to build a pipe inside it, to prevent the pressure from collapsing it. If you are building your city out of handwavium, might as well build a tunnel out of it.

Answer (score 3):

### Chord tunnel

Don't attempt to lay the tunnel on the sea bottom. Go under the sea bottom. 
Exploit the curvature of the earth to make a *chord tunnel* - laser straight.  Normal tunnels are not laser straight, they have a vertical curve to match the earth's curvature.

Take the famous picture of power lines curving over Lake Pontchartrain.  If you started a tunnel a mile or two landside of shore on each end, and built it as a *chord tunnel*, it probably would be entirely beneath the bottom of the lake.

Answer (score 1):

If you build a tunnel for long distances underwater, you will run into a variety of problems, one of which is the time the journey would take on long trips. To go from Honolulu, Hawaii to San Francisco, California would take 2,393 miles at best train speed, it would take 8 hours of travel time.

Imagine if you could go anywhere in only 38 minutes.

What you really need is a Gravity Train.

[image: Gravity Train]

A gravity train is a means of transportation intended to go between two points on the surface of a sphere, following a straight tunnel that goes directly from one point to the other through the interior of the sphere.

[image: Description of Tunnel]

In a large body such as the Earth, this train could be left to accelerate using just the force of gravity, since, during the first half of the trip (from the point of departure until the middle), the downward pull towards the center of gravity would pull it towards the destination. During the second half of the trip, the acceleration would be in the opposite direction relative to the trajectory, but (ignoring the effects of friction) the speed acquired before would be enough to cancel this deceleration exactly (so that the train would reach its destination with speed equal to zero). The math works out that from the time entering the tunnel to the time exiting would take around 38-45 minutes.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_train

Good luck with your choo choo.